# Algorithm compare 2 list and find the way with the least amount of errors

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm having some trouble making an algorithm to calculate the difference between 2 lists.

The first list is the **expected** list, which means, this it's how it should look if everything went according to plan.

The second list is a list of how it **actually went**.

I need to compare these to list and find out if a checkpoint is **missing** or if there is an **error note** which means that there has been noted a checkpoint that is not supposed to be noted. The **sequence of the checkpoints matter**, it has to be in the same sequence as the expected.

My problem is how do I compare these two lists and make it and find the fewest errors, and mark these errors.

At the moment I have made 3 classes.

The expected class:

```
public class IdealRouteCheckpoint : ICheckpoint
{
    public IdealRouteCheckpoint(string checkpointValue, int minTime = 0, int maxTime = 0, bool defective = false, bool optional = false)
    {
        CheckpointValue = checkpointValue;
        Defective = defective;
        Optional = optional;
        MinTime = minTime;
        MaxTime = maxTime;
    }

    public string CheckpointValue { get; set; }

    //Used for when a Checkpoint this missing for when it placed wrong
    public bool Defective { get; set; } 
    //Used for when you do somehitng and know that people risk taking it
    public bool Optional { get; set; }

    //Used for OTK and HTK
    public int MinTime { get; set; }
    public int MaxTime { get; set; }
}
```

The class with the checkpoint from how to actually went.

```
public class NotedCheckPoint : ICheckpoint
{
    public NotedCheckPoint(string checkpointValue)
    {
        CheckpointValue = checkpointValue;
    }

    public string CheckpointValue { get; set; }


}
```

Then I'm thinking about making a third class that is supposed to have the result and the markings of the errors, so I'm in the end can print the result to a PDF. That class looks something like this.

```
public class ResultCheckpoint : ICheckpoint
{
    public ResultCheckpoint(string checkpointValue, bool missing = false, bool errorNote = false, int early = 0, int late = 0)
    {
        CheckpointValue = checkpointValue;
        Missing = missing;
        ErrorNote = errorNote;
        Early = early;
        Late = late;
    }

    public string CheckpointValue { get; set; }

    //MK when a checkpoint is missing on the controlCard
    public bool Missing { get; set; }
    //FN when there is a checkpoint too much on the controlCard
    public bool ErrorNote { get; set; }

    //When teams are too early to a HTK or OTK
    public int Early { get; set; }
    //When teams are too late to a HTK or OTK
    public int Late { get; set; }
}
```

I have made a picture of what I want to achieve, but I think I need to explain a couple of things.

The left column is the expected, cells where there is nothing is to make space for an error note.

The Result column is what was actually noted. Cells, where there is nothing, is to make space for a missing checkpoint.

Every error note and missing checkpoint cost 25 points.

The last thing is there is a time, but I think I can handle that part when I have found a solution to my problem.

[image: Here is a picture to illustrate what I mean]

Comment: can you sort them by one property that must be the same in both lists and then use a hash(dictionary of key value...where the key is the this property you chose and value is the actual object). Then you will compare these dictionary values based on key

Comment: I compare be the checkpointValue if thats what you mean

Comment: I meant prepare key value pair of the expected and the actual. Example [A, expectedObj1], [B,expectedObject2], [A, actualObj1], [C,actualObj2]. For example here, B is missing.. I m giving you an idea not a solution